# How do I connect the Sonicmaster subwoofer that came with the ASUS Q550L?

Tags: laptop

No instructions are provided to describe the process of connecting the wireless subwoofer to the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The compact subwoofer plugs into an audio out port that’s on the right-hand side of each (Asus) notebook (in your case it could be left side as well). Anyway - find an audio out port and plug it in.

[image]